# CSS animation with nth-child()

Tags: html, css, animation, css-selectors

I wanted to experiment with different animation effect.
The idea was - appear some child divs from the top, and some (nth-child) from the left ...

html

```
   <div class="test">
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
</div>
```

css

```
.test{
   position:fixed;
   top:100px; 
   left:400px;
   border-radius:0%;
   width:800px;
   height:500px;
   display:inline-block;
   background-color:red;
   animation:mapp 5s ease;
   -webkit-animation:mapp 5s ease;
   -o-animation:mapp 5s ease;
   -moz-animation:mapp 5s ease;
   -ms-animation:mapp 5s ease;
}

.test div{
            position:relative;
            display:inline-block;
            margin:20px;

            border-radius:25%;
            width:90px;
            height:90px;
            background-color:black;
            opacity:1;

            animation:mapp2 6s ease;
            -webkit-animation:mapp2 6s ease;
            -o-animation:mapp2 6s ease;
            -moz-animation:mapp2 6s ease;
            -ms-animation:mapp2 6s ease;

   }
```

animation

```
@-webkit-keyframes mapp{from{border-radius:50%; width:50px; height:50px;}}
@-moz-keyframes mapp{from{border-radius:50%; width:50px; height:50px;}}
@-o-keyframes mapp{from{border-radius:50%; width:50px; height:50px;}}
@-ms-keyframes mapp{from{border-radius:50%; width:50px; height:50px;}}
@keyframes mapp{from{border-radius:50%; width:50px; height:50px;}}


@-webkit-keyframes mapp2{0%{opacity:0; border-radius:0px; margin-   top:-100px;}
                     90%{opacity:0;border-radius:0px; margin-top:-100px;}
 }
 @-moz-keyframes mapp2{0%{opacity:0;border-radius:0px; margin-top:-100px;}
                     90%{opacity:0;border-radius:0px; margin-top:-100px;}
 }
 @-o-keyframes mapp2{0%{opacity:0;border-radius:0px; margin-top:-100px;}
                     90%{opacity:0;border-radius:0px; margin-top:-100px;}
 }
 @-ms-keyframes mapp2{0%{opacity:0;border-radius:0px; margin-top:-100px;}
                     90%{opacity:0;border-radius:0px; margin-top:-100px;} 
 }
 @keyframes mapp2{0%{opacity:0;border-radius:0px; margin-top:-100px;}
                     90%{opacity:0;border-radius:0px; margin-top:-100px;}
 }
```

This part worked perfectly, but when i add

css

```
.test div:nth-child(2n){
animation:mapp3 5s ease;
-webkit-animation:mapp3 5s ease;
-o-animation:mapp3 5s ease;
-moz-animation:mapp3 5s ease;
-ms-animation:mapp3 5s ease;
}
```

and animation

```
@-webkit-keyframes mapp3{0%{opacity:0; border-radius:0px; margin-     left:-100px;}
                     90%{opacity:0;border-radius:0px; margin-left:-100px;}
}
```

Something went wrong... "nth-child(2n)"  starts to appear from the left, but other divs appear not from the top, but from their final position ... It looks like animation ("from margin-top") breaks down, animaion - opacity and border-radius animation are still ok ...

Sorry for my english, hope you understand the question.

Thanks.

UPD:  https://jsfiddle.net/3z6tj/1/    - with  nth-child(2n)
UPD2: https://jsfiddle.net/3z6tj/3/    - without nth-child(2n)

Comment: Could you make a jsfiddle or codepen?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/3z6tj/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this piece of code https://jsfiddle.net/3z6tj/4/

```
.test{
  position:fixed;
  top:100px; 
  left:50px;
  border-radius:0%;
  width:800px;
  height:500px;
  display:inline-block;
  background-color:red;
  animation:mapp 3s ease;
  -webkit-animation:mapp 3s ease;
  -o-animation:mapp 3s ease;
  -moz-animation:mapp 3s ease;
  -ms-animation:mapp 3s ease;
}

.test div{
  position:relative;
  display:inline-block;
  margin:20px;
  border-radius:25%;
  width:90px;
  height:90px;

  opacity:1;
  animation:mapp2 7s ease;
  -webkit-animation:mapp2 7s ease;
  -o-animation:mapp2 5s ease;
  -moz-animation:mapp2 5s ease;
  -ms-animation:mapp2 5s ease;
}

.test div:nth-child(even){
  animation:mapp3 8s ease;
  -webkit-animation:mapp3 8s ease;
  -o-animation:mapp3 7s ease;
  -moz-animation:mapp3 7s ease;
  -ms-animation:mapp3 7s ease;
  background-color:black;
}

.test div:nth-child(odd){
  background-color:yellow;
  position:relative;
  top:0px;
}
@-webkit-keyframes mapp3{0%{position:relative;opacity:0; border-radius:0px; margin-left:-100px;}
  90%{position:relative;opacity:0;border-radius:0px; margin-left:-100px;}
}

@-webkit-keyframes mapp{from{border-radius:50%; width:50px; height:50px;}}
@-moz-keyframes mapp{from{border-radius:50%; width:50px; height:50px;}}
@-o-keyframes mapp{from{border-radius:50%; width:50px; height:50px;}}
@-ms-keyframes mapp{from{border-radius:50%; width:50px; height:50px;}}
@keyframes mapp{from{border-radius:50%; width:50px; height:50px;}}


@-webkit-keyframes mapp2{0%{position:relative;opacity:0; border-radius:0px; margin-top:-100px;}
  90%{opacity:0;border-radius:0px; position:relative;top:-100px;}
}
```